# Add numbering to `thebibliography` header

Tags: bibliographies, numbering

I have a latex page and am showing references in this structure:

```
\section{References}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{aa6401}
    ... ...

\bibitem{aa6060}
    ... ...

\end{thebibliography}
```

The heading **References** is showed twice though. This is because both `\section{References}` and the `begin{thebibliography}` writes out this header.

But while `\section{References}` is numbered accordingly with the rest of the page headers, the `begin{thebibliography}` part writes the header **References** without numbering.

I will now remove the `\section{References}`. But how can I make the `begin{thebibliography}` add the numbering to the header?

I use the `article` documentclass.

Comment: `thebibliography` is defined in the document class, probably with `\section*` to suppress the number.  it's necessary to know what document class you're using in order to give accurate advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using the standard `article` class, it's as easy as adding

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{*}{}{}{}
```

to your document preamble. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{*}{}{}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Text}

Something.

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{duck} D. Duck, Life of Uncle Scrooge, Duckburg, 2012

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ooh ducks! `:)`